# How to route to specific screen? How to Perform Nested route in custom_Navigator properly

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator, nested-routes

I using custom Navigator package for routing.
I have 4 screens say:
**

```
ScreenA()
ScreenB()
ScreenC()
ScreenD()
```

`ScreenA()` contains nested routes.
i.e if we route under `ScreenA()` it goes to some other screen which is child
`childOfScreenA()` again i am routing from  `childOfScreenA()` to other `childOfScreenA's` child
it works fine.but when i press bottom-nav button say  `ScreenB()`* it shows the `childOfScreenA()`,
and i have to press it again to reach to `ScreenB()`. whenever there is 3 level route custom Navigator package not working. Is there any solution of this?